# Children's "Little Gemarah"?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, talmud-gemara, children-parenting, chinuch-education

My family enjoys this English language Little Midrash [series](http://www.mitzvahland.com/by5017.html?ref=lexity&_vs=google&_vm=productsearch).

Does something like an English language 'Little Gemarah' (ie introduces reasoning logic) exist for children 6-12 years old?

Comment: Just in case you don't know, they also have that series on parts of Nakh https://seforimdeals.com/store15/index.php/all-books-seforim/midrash-mdrw/the-little-family-midrash-says-7-vol-set.html

Comment: Pirkei Avot says to start teaching Gemara, by which they mean Gemara-type logical delving into Halacha, at age 15. My understanding, based partially on personal experience, is that kids typically aren't cognitively prepared to truly handle and appreciate it until around then.

Comment: @ Daniel ... You know, that's a very smart idea. There are learning aids, and English stories of the Gemara for kids. I am not aware of what you are asking for though. It would be nice.

Comment: @ Isaac Moses - True, but for some reason, our system today in the frum Yeshivah world seems to throw the kids into it at 10 - 11. (and Mishnah even earlier)

Comment: Would not be at all surprised if you could get them in/from South Korea; not sure about hashkafic value: http://www.newyorker.com/books/page-turner/how-the-talmud-became-a-best-seller-in-south-korea

Comment: I recall seeing a Daf Yomi for Kids worksheet floating around somewhere. A quick search found the website: http://www.dafyomi4kids.com/

Answer (score 2):

[Here is](https://dafyomi.co.il/section.php?gid=14&sid=19) Masechet Yevamot broken down into worksheets per daf. I am unclear what ages they are meant for, but they do seem very colorful and something somewhat appealing to a younger scholar. ([They've even printed some of them](http://www.jewishusedbooks.com/prodview.asp?idProduct=69115))

However, since you adressed preparations in Gemara-logic, I recommend this, which is exactly for that:

[A Yiddishe Kop: Visual Brainteasers for the Keen Eye and Sharp Mind](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1943281823)

([and volume II](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1635870925))

Comment: A Yiddishe Kop is very very good, for both kids and parents. It takes solid knowledge of *halacha* though. Exists in English and Hebrew